# ImportError: No module named _sqlite3 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Ive compiled python 2.7 and django 1.3.
When working with django I find that it reports..

```
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Ive ensure that all the correct sqlite packages are installed and recompiled but still no joy.

```
[root@monty Python-2.7.3]# rpm -qa | grep sql
sqlite-devel-3.3.6-5
postgresql-libs-8.1.23-6.el5_8
sqlite-3.3.6-5
python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1
sqlite-devel-3.3.6-5
sqlite-3.3.6-5
python-sqlite2-2.6.3-1.el5.rf
postgresql-libs-8.1.23-6.el5_8
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you just do `import sqlite3` in a Python2.7 interpreter - what do you get?

Comment: >>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3

Comment: When you say recompiled, did you do another configure (once modules were in place) before making?

Comment: yep just did the following 
 1005  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python2.7
 1006  make && make altinstall

Comment: Okay, but `make altinstall` doesn't install any shared modules...

Comment: I just tried a make install but still the same issue (??)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21232/discussion-between-felix001-and-jon-clements)

Comment: removed the make altinstall, and remember to do the setup at the end and this is now working.

Comment: phew - took you long enough ;)

Comment: unfortanlty i get the same error when using virtualenv..ideas

Answer (score 6):

Install

```
sqlite-devel
```

and more importantly rebuild Python.

Comment: I already have these installed.

Package sqlite-devel-3.3.6-5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package sqlite-devel-3.3.6-5.i386 already installed and latest version

Comment: If I may ask did you try rebuilding Python?